# How to make a tree function generic?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have a recursive reconstructTree function:

```
type Tree = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  children: Tree[];
};

type ReconstructedTree = {
  id: string;
  children: ReconstructedTree[];
};

const reconstructTree = (
  tree: Tree[]
): ReconstructedTree[] =>
  tree.map(({ id, children }) => ({
    id: String(id),
    children: reconstructTree(children),
  }));
```

What it does now is take in an infinitely large tree object array, and replaces id:number with string type (id:string).

What I want to do is make this into a generic function. Such as:

```
const reconstructTree = <T, ReturnType>(tree: T[]): ReturnType[] =>
  tree.map(({ id, children }) => ({
    id: String(id),
    children: reconstructTree(children),
  }));


// this is the error I get from typeScript

Type '{ id: string; children: ReconstructedTree[]; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType[]'.
  Type '{ id: string; children: ReconstructedTree[]; }' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType'.
    'ReturnType' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ id: string; children: ReconstructedTree[]; }'.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I want to be able to call it like this:

```
reconstructTree<Tree, ReconstructedTree[]>(tree);
```

Not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should tell TS that `T` is an object with `id` and `children` props.

```js
type Tree = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  children: Tree[];
};

type ReconstructedTree = {
  id: string;
  children: ReconstructedTree[];
};

const reconstructTree = <T extends Tree>(tree: T[]): ReconstructedTree[] =>
  tree.map(({ id, children }) => ({
    id: String(id),
    children: reconstructTree(children),
  }));
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgThaBeKBvAUFKBLAJgLigDsBXAWwCMI4BuTYgQzIkIGdg5siBzOrAYwAW2ADa4ERQvEQBtALp0AvnXShIUAEoR%20AeyLs4JfsAi5pyNPTxsOXXvSGjxESZu16DRk2YQR5SlXRdfWAoBGDPY3MoFAAeGCgIAA8TIlxWWF8APgAKDkQpeQBKQi0Iji9Tc3kYrPp8iAA6MgYwHJzUHFwAGihHMQkoRSLaqA76LGsoAGVbHhy8Iu6JvuEBl0Jwjwqo3xz%205yIl%20mGiuiA)

Also you should not use `ReturnType`

Why `ReturnType` does not work?

```js
const reconstructTree = <T extends Tree, ReturnType>(tree: T[]): ReturnType[] =>
  tree.map(({ id, children }) => ({
    id: String(id),
    children: reconstructTree(children),
  }));


const result = reconstructTree<any, number[]>([{ id: 42, name: 'John', children: [] }])
```

Because you can do smth like that:`reconstructTree<any, number[]>`

> I want to be able to call it like this:`reconstructTree<Tree, ReconstructedTree[]>(tree);`

In 92.4% cases, you should not use explicit generic parameters to annotate return type. TS should infer arguments an return types on his own.

*When do I need to use explicit generic parameters?*

When your function expects an array of some type but you provided an empty array.
Consider this example:

```js
const foo = <T,>(arr: T[]) => arr

const result = foo([]) // never
```

Because TS is unable to infer the type of empty array elements it is infered to `never`. Hence in this case you need to provide explicit generic:

```js
const foo = <T,>(arr: T[]) => arr

const result = foo<number>([]) // number[]
```

Comment: Thank you captain-yossarian, I wanted to pass in a generic because when someone is using this function for general usage. When T extends Tree, then that is already typed Tree.